# Has anyone successfully embedded the LiveAgent script into a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, liveagent, napili

I'm trying to integrate LiveAgent into a Salesforce Napili community that is built entirely using Lightning Components. If I embed the script using:

LiveAgent doesn't load or show up at all in Google Chrome or Safari. What they told me I need to do is have the actual  tags with their provided code inside of it directly in each page. I tried adding it to a VisualForce page and embedding it that way but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas or a solution for how to get actual script tags into a Napili Community Page? It has to be in the body of the HTML, not the head.

UPDATE:  Switching the component to version 39 fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is an out of box snapins chat component thats provided in winter 18 release thats working and functional.

[image]

You cannot directly load the script tag in lightning components .